# Unable to bind data to scope object after service call using $RESOURCE in typescript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-resource, typescript1.5

I am pulling data from api and trying to bind to variable , I have debugged code getting data from API but it is not getting binded to scope object here is my code

**Service:**

```
module application.common {
    angular.module("common.service", ["ngresource"])

   export class DataAccessService {

        static $inject = ["$resource"]; /// To avoid minificaton errors i.e prameters thgar are use to be defines and should be in order.

        constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService,private $http:ng.IHttpService) {
        }

        getProductResource() {                      
            return this.$resource("http://localhost:50000/api/values/GetProducts", { 'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false } }).get().$promise.then(function (response) {
                var obj = new product();
                //debugger;
                obj.title = response.title;
                obj.showImage = response.showImage;
                obj.products = response.objDetails;
                return obj;
            });            
        }        

    }

    angular.module("common.service",['ngResource']).service("dataAccessService", DataAccessService);
}
```

Here is the Controller code where I am calling service and consuming

```
class ProductListCtrl1 {        
        obj: IProduct;

        static $inject = ["dataAccessService"];
        constructor(private dataAccessService: application.common.DataAccessService) {

            this.obj = new product();

            dataAccessService.getProductResource().then(function (response) {
                alert('1');
                debugger;
                this.obj = response;   // I'm getting response here with all properties
            });
            alert('2  ' + this.obj.title); // This alert is firing first rather than alert 1

            this.obj.title = "Product List Type Script11"; // This is getting binded what ever properties I'm binding here are loaded 

        }
    }
var app1 = angular.module("productManagement1", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource','common.service']);

    app1.controller("ProductListCtrl1", ProductListCtrl1);
```

**Entity:**

```
interface IProduct {
    title: string;
    showImage: boolean;
    products: productDetails[];
}

class product implements IProduct {
    title: string;
    showImage: boolean;
    products: productDetails[];
}
```

As per the comments I am attaching my response object

```
$promise:d
  $$state:Object
  __proto__: Object
$resolved:true
objDetails:Array[3]
showImage:false
title:"Tetsing Typescropit"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Please paste your api response here. I want to check the json object in response.

Comment: @Gurpinder  added response object

Comment: When you do `this.obj = response;` the scope is different.

Comment: @CodrinEugeniu : ya I understood that , that is why I'm unable to view data... so what is the solution , how to bind data to the initial scope after getting data back from service?

Comment: Sudhir please provide the json if possible. I want to check for empty array or object in json